# ¿Como puedo asignarle a un hilo una tarea?

Tags: java, hilos

Buenas tengo un problema con Threads en Java cuando ejecuto mi programa con cuatro Threads el tiempo de ejecucion es mayor a que si lo ejecuto con 1 y no entiendo la razon. Basicamente lo que quiero es asignarle a cada Threads la cantidad de archivos a analizar. Este es el codigo que me da problemas.

```
 public class analiza extends Thread 
{ 
private Stemm_es es;

public analiza() { 
     es = new Stemm_es();
} 

@Override
public void run() { 

    System.out.println(getName()); 

File file1=new File("E:\\Escuela\\TESIS\\Prueba\\Prueba\\Entrada");
    File [] archivos=file1.listFiles();

    File file=new File("E:\\Escuela\\TESIS\\Prueba\\Prueba\\Salida\\ale.txt");
        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
    for(int e = 0; e < archivos.length; e++){

        String word ="";
        try {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File("E:\\Escuela\\TESIS\\Prueba\\Prueba\\Entrada\\"+archivos[e].getName()));
             while(sc.hasNextLine())
                {
                  String titulo=sc.nextLine();
                  word+=" "+titulo;
                }
             sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Analizar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


            String [] palabras={"él", "http", "www", "ésta", "éstas", "éste", "éstos", "última", "últimas", "último", "últimos", "a", "añadió", "aún", "aun", "actualmente", "adelante","yo"};
            String [] mama=word.split(" ");
            String [] papa=new String[mama.length];
            int a=mama.length;
            for (int i =0;i<a;i++){   
                for(int l=0;l<palabras.length;l++){
                    if (mama[a-1].equals(palabras[l]))
                    a=a-1;
                    if(mama[i].equals(palabras[l]))  
                    mama[i]="" ;   
                }       
                if (mama[i].length()>=1) {
                    mama[i]=mama[i].replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "");
                    mama[i]= mama[i].trim();
                    String raiz= es.stemm(mama[i]);
                    papa[i]=raiz;
                    pw.append(" "+papa[i]);

                }

            }
            pw.println("                                                                                                                 ");


    } 
   pw.close();




} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Analizar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

System.out.println("El programa ha ﬁnalizado"); 
} 




   public static void main (String[] args) { 


   analiza hiloUno = new analiza(); 
   analiza hiloDos = new analiza(); 
   analiza hiloTres = new analiza();
   analiza hiloCuatro = new analiza();
   hiloUno.start(); 
   hiloDos.start();
   hiloTres.start();
   hiloCuatro.start();
   try {
   hiloUno.join(); 
   hiloDos.join(); 
   hiloTres.join();
   hiloCuatro.join();

   } catch (InterruptedException ie) { 
   }
  System.out.println("El programa ha ﬁnalizado"); 
  } 



  }
```

Comment: Todos los hilos usan los mismos archivos. que sentido tiene?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Es normal que tarde más, no estás dividiendo tareas entre hilos, estás creando cuatro hilos con la misma tarea, o al menos eso es lo que me parece a simple vista.

Para asignar una tarea a cada hilo, deberías implementar cuatro clases que hereden de `Thread`, pero con distinta implementación del método `run`, aunque no siempre es así.

También puedes crear hilos de la clase `Thread` y pasarle las diferentes tareas en el constructor, como clases anónimas que implementen la interfaz `Runnable`.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /* Código de la tarea 1 */
    }
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /* Código de la tarea 2 */
    }
});
```

O bien, si utilizas Java 8, puedes hacerlo con una expresión lambda, que hace que el código se reduzca.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        /* El código de la tarea va aquí */
    }
);
```

En cualquier caso tienes que tener en cuenta que el código y el trabajo no se divide solo, ni se hace la tarea más rápido solo porque la crees dentro de una clase que herede de `Thread`.

En algunas ocasiones, si solo divides una tarea en dos, puede ser que el *overhead* debido a la creación y manejo de hilos puede hacer que el programa tarde más en hacer determinada tarea (no es lo común, y menos aún en entornos multiprocesador, pero puede pasar).

Comment: yo tengo que llamar a la clase que contiene los hilos desde otra clase ¿como yo lo haria si lo implemento asi como me dijiste?

Comment: Puedes crear distintas clases que hereden de `Thread`, o bien lo que yo he hecho, utilizar clases anónimas par no tener que crear tantas clases. En cualquier caso, se llama al constructor desde la clase que quera crear los hilos, y en tu caso eso seía dentro del `main`.